# Parametrizing a surface S

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have a small question here involving parametrizing surfaces.

Given the surface $S$ in $R^{3}$ given by the equation $(x-1)^2 + y^2 + (z+2)^2 = 1$

Provide the parametrized surface element for $S$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $S$ is the sphere of radius $1$ and center $(1,0,-2)$, whence a parametrization is given by:
$$(\theta,\varphi)\mapsto (1+\cos(\theta)\cos(\varphi),\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi),-2+\sin(\theta)).$$
Whence, the first fundamental form of $S$ is given by:
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\cos(\theta)^2\mathrm{d}\varphi^2.$$
Finally, the surface element of $S$ is:
$$\mathrm{d}\sigma=\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\varphi.$$

Comment: Why is it $cos(\theta)\cos(\varphi)$ and $cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi)$ and $sin(\theta)$? From Spherical coordinates?

Comment: That is exactly what it is!

Comment: Would it not be respectively $$(\theta,\varphi)\mapsto (1+\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi),-2+\cos(\theta)).$$ Instead? Im looking at my notes on converting to spherical, and x, y, z are described as above

Comment: I depends if you work with the latitude or the co-latitude.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your query but follows the "why?" question posed to CFalcon below.
If you're familiar with surfaces of revolution, the derivation is easy. A circle that is rotated around a diameter generates a sphere.

The parametric equations for a surface of revolution are:

$$
\left(f(u)\cos v, f(u)\sin v, g(u)\right)
$$

Where $\left(f(u), g(u)\right)$ are the parametric equations of the rotated curve. For a circle, they are $\left(r \cos u, r \sin u\right)$. Therefore, the parametric equations of a sphere are:

$$
\left(r \cos u \cos v, r \cos u \sin v, r \sin u\right)
$$